# AngularJS | Better approach for conditional initialization in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our current AngularJS application, we have three tabs and 3 different controllers are used to bind them.

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
myApp.controller('Tab1Ctrl', function(){
  // logic to initialize Tab1 
});

myApp.controller('Tab2Ctrl', function(){
  // logic to intialize Tab2
});

myApp.controller('Tab3Ctrl', function(){
   // logic to initialize Tab3
});
```

Our intent is to merge these controllers into a single one but initialize these 3 tabs accordingly. We're using `resolve` in `ui-router` for this. All the data that is required for a particular tab is loaded within resolve and current state name is saved in `MyService`.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider){

   $stateProvider.state('tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        controller: 'TabCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
        resolve: {
            tabData: function(MyService) {
                MyService.setState('tab1');
                return MyService.getTab1Data();
            }
        }
    }).state('tab2', {
        url: '/tab2',
        controller: 'TabCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html',
        resolve: {
            tabData: function(MyService) {
                MyService.setState('tab2');
                return MyService.getTab2Data();
            }
        }
    });

   });

  myApp.controller('TabCtrl', function($scope, MyService, tabData){

    /* Check for state name and initialize */
    if(MyService.getState() === 'tab1'){
      /* Use the data loaded in resolve and assign it to scope*/
      $scope.tab1Prop = tabData.prop1;
    }

    else if(MyService.getState() === 'tab2'){
      /* Use the data loaded in resolve and assign it to scope*/
      $scope.tab2Prop = tabData.prop2;
    }
  });
```

Note that properties that we need to set on `$scope` are differentfor each tab.
Finally my question is, Is there any better way to do this conditional initialization in a single controller ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that'd be more efficient for this sort of static matching is using a switch statement, or at the very least storing the result of `MyService.getState()` in a variable, and comparing against that, rather than calling it for each check.

Comment: Thanks. But we already employ both your suggestions in our actual code. The code samples that I mentioned above are to explain our approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your state provider:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider){

   $stateProvider.state('tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        controller: 'TabCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
        resolve: {
            tabData: { tabState: 'tab1',
                       initData: {'tab1propA': 'tabby1valueA',
                                  'tab1propB': 'tabby1valueB'
                                 }
                     }
            }
       }
    }).state('tab2', {
        url: '/tab2',
        controller: 'TabCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html',
        resolve: {
            tabData: { tabState: 'tab2',
                       initData: {'tab2propA': 'tabby2valueA',
                                  'tab2propB': 'tabby2valueB'
                                 }
                     }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Your controller:

```
myApp.controller('TabCtrl', function($scope, MyService, tabData){

    angular.forEach(tabData.initData, function(value, key) {
        $scope[key] = value;
    };

    /* Check for state name and initialize */
    if(tabData.tabState === 'tab1'){
        //whatever else for tab1
    } else if(tabData.tabState === 'tab2'){
        //whatever else for tab2
    };
});
```